# Reshaping dataframe of ranked preferences over options in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where each row contains some individual's rankings (first, second, third, fourth) of four different options (1,2,3,4)

| first | second | third | fourth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 2 |

I would instead like the rows to correspond to the votes, and the columns to correspond to the options

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| third | second | fourth | first |
| third | second | first | fourth |
| first | third | fourth | second |

And eventually clean up and get something like:

| option_1 | option_2 | option_3 | option_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 2 |

Any idea of how I could go about this? (And any better question title suggestions are very much appreciated!)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is wrong. If you have options in rows and you want the order in which each option is chosen you must use `order` That is

```r
df <- data.frame(first = c(3,3,1),
                 second = c(2,2,3),
                 third = c(4,4,4),
                 fourth = c(1,1,2)) 

print(df)
#>   first second third fourth
#> 1     3      2     4      1
#> 2     3      2     4      1
#> 3     1      3     4      2

new_df <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, order)))

colnames(new_df) <- paste0("Option_", 1:4) 

print(new_df)
#>   Option_1 Option_2 Option_3 Option_4
#> 1        4        2        1        3
#> 2        4        2        1        3
#> 3        1        4        2        3
```